# Retrieve decimal data from mysql and put into an array

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

I have a mysql table, with only one register, where the `price` field is of `decimal(6,2)` type, with the value of `60.35`

Consider the code above:

```
$prices = mysql_query("SELECT id, price FROM products");
while ($pr = mysql_fetch_assoc($prices)) {
    $prics[$pr['id']]=$pr['price'];
    echo $pr['price'].' - '.$prics[$pr['id']]."\n";
}
```

The output is incorrect:

> 60.35 - 6

The correct would be:

> 60.35 - 60.35

I tried the same situation without mysql query:

```
$var = array(60.35,'60.35',60);
$var2[0] = $var[0];
$var2[1] = $var[1];
print_r($var2);
```

And it works as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 60.35
    [1] => 60.35
)
```

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that PHP converts the second float to a string because it's concatenated to a string while it consider the first one a float

EDIT - no this works perfectly, it must be something else

http://codepad.org/UbeJ20Wh

Comment: The problem has origin in the mysql query

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is likely

```
$prics[$pr['id']]=$pr['price'];
```

Try forcing the type like:

```
settype($prics[$pr['id']], "float");
$prics[$pr['id']]=$pr['price'];
echo $pr['price'].' - '.$prics[$pr['id']]."\n";
```

Comment: It returns another error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: Try adding a new variable $p, setting `$p = $pr['price']`, then setting `$prics[$pr['id']] = $p`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by initializing the array var before its use:

```
$prics = array();
```